# Error while using jupyter-datatables plugin in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working with some data frames and recently came across **jupyter-datatables** plugin that gives a better look and feel of data frames when loaded into jupyter notebook.

so the below commands worked well for me for the first time-

```
pip install jupyter-require
pip install jupyter-datatables
from jupyter_datatables import init_datatables_mode
init_datatables_mode()
```

but now I am facing issues while loading the tables and getting error messages like the ones highlighted below:
[image]

OR this -

[image]

I am tired of reloading it ..sometimes it works but mostly it doesn't.
Tried finding answers but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

The solution below works for me:

`%load_ext jupyter_require`

`init_datatables_mode()`

If your error persists you can try:

`%load_ext jupyter_require`

`%requirejs d3 https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min`

`init_datatables_mode()`